# All popups became white

Tags: android

After updating old android project to be able to build project with Android Studio 3.2.1, all popups became white.

All AlertDialog, ProgressDialog, Spinner got white background and white text.

If i change theme in the app, some text become readable but whiteness persist.

I solved some of them by hacks like this:
`progressDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.DKGRAY));`

but this doesn't work everywhere.

What can be the cause?

This is first time i work with android in seven year, i was doing iOS before, so this is new territory for me.

Update:

Comments helped to pinpoint that issue was regarding themes.
Now, challenge was digging out what was causing white backgrounds.

I had to set parent to my custom attribute:

```
parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat"
```

So in my custom theme there was this attribute: `android:alertDialogTheme`

```
    <style name="CustomMobileTheme.Base.Black" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat">

    <item name="android:alertDialogTheme">@style/Theme.AppCompat.Dialog.Alert</item>

    <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/actionBarColorBlackTheme</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">#000000</item>
```

That was making all this mess. I have no idea what `android:alertDialogTheme` does, it is not specified in Spinner documentation and i had to manually comment out about 200 attributes in the theme, to dig out this culprit and spend about 13 hours of my private time. I wish to the developer who made this suffer some bad karma.

Comment: I am sure for 90% that the problem is in app theme. Check app default styles.

Comment: Easy solution for this problem is to use a custom design for all dialogs (not a hack though) . And this issue is happening due to app theme.

Comment: Theme issue it is. Why is is so? Why android do not use my theme? Is there a place in project where you set the theme. I am trying to evade setting theme for each popup manually in xml file. `android:theme="@style/spinnerStyleBase"`

Comment: @Link182 Where do you check that?

Answer (score 0):

All AlertDialog, ProgressDialog, Spinner got white background and white text.
It may Becuase of "colorAccent" in your application theme is white.

Please check your theme for "colorAccent". If not specified then please specify with color which you want. check below code.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```